# Where to instantiate and populate view models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically in my application I'm starting to get some heavy view models (and view models within these view models).
So when I instantiate and populate them in my controllers, the controller methods seem to get quite thick (even though all the logic is handled in the model layer and the controller only calls methods to retrieve data to insert into the view model).

Where would be the best place to instantiate and populate my view models?

Comment: Generally I would instantiate view models in the controller, since their only real purpose is to be passed into a view.  Can you provide an example from your code that you think can be improved?  Perhaps you can move some of the logic that's happening in the controller into the view model itself?

Answer (score 1):

> Where would be the best place to instantiate and populate my view models?

That would be in the mapping layer of your application. For example if you are using [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org) your controller code might look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    DomainModel model = repository.Get(id);
    ViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<DomainModel, ViewModel>(model);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

or with custom action filters it might even be further simplified to:

```
[AutoMap(typeof(DomainModel), typeof(ViewModel))]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    DomainModel model = repository.Get(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

Of course if you don't use AutoMapper but some custom code, that's not a problem. You will simply inject some mapping interface into your controller that will take care of this work.